# Flutter iOS build failed: Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

The runs fine on Android but when I run it for iOS. It shows a few warnings but also an error. Following are the logs.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
 
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)⡿
Compiler message:
../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-1.17.3/lib/src/snackbar/snack_route.dart:279:8: Error: The
method 'SnackRoute.install' has more required arguments than those of overridden method 'OverlayRoute.install'.
  void install(OverlayEntry insertionPoint) {
       ^
../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:41:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('install').
  void install() {
       ^
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)⡿../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-1.17.3/lib/src/routes/default_route.dart:242:9: Error: No named
parameter with the name 'animation'.
        animation: animation,
        ^^^^^^^^^
../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:435:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments
don't match.
  CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)⣟../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-1.17.3/lib/src/snackbar/snack_route.dart:289:18: Error: Too
many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    super.install(insertionPoint);
                 ^
Running pod install...                                             11.5s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
Xcode build done.                                           63.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/apple/desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.15.1/darwin/Classes/AudioplayersPlugin.m:88:37:
    warning: incompatible pointer types sending 'FlutterEngine *' to parameter of type 'NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger> * _Nonnull'
    [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                        binaryMessenger:_headlessEngine];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/apple/desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.15.1/darwin/Classes/AudioplayersPlugin.h:2:
    /Users/apple/Desktop/dev/upwork/body_alarm/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h:178:74: note: passing argument
    to parameter 'messenger' here
                          binaryMessenger:(NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger>*)messenger;
                                                                             ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/apple/desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibration-1.4.0/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m:6:4: warning:
    'SwiftVibrationPlugin' is only available on iOS 13.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
      [SwiftVibrationPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from
    /Users/apple/desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibration-1.4.0/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m:2:
    /Users/apple/Desktop/dev/upwork/body_alarm/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/vibration/vibration.framework/Headers/vibration-Swift.h
    :213:12: note: 'SwiftVibrationPlugin' has been marked as being introduced in iOS 13.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
    @interface SwiftVibrationPlugin : NSObject <FlutterPlugin>
               ^
    /Users/apple/desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibration-1.4.0/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m:6:4: note:
    enclose 'SwiftVibrationPlugin' in an @available check to silence this warning
      [SwiftVibrationPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.

    Compiler message:
    ../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-1.17.3/lib/src/snackbar/snack_route.dart:279:8: Error: The
    method 'SnackRoute.install' has more required arguments than those of overridden method 'OverlayRoute.install'.
      void install(OverlayEntry insertionPoint) {
           ^
    ../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:41:8: Context: This is the overridden method
    ('install').
      void install() {
           ^
    ../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-1.17.3/lib/src/routes/default_route.dart:242:9: Error: No
    named parameter with the name 'animation'.
            animation: animation,
            ^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:435:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the
    arguments don't match.
      CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition({
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../../desktop/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-1.17.3/lib/src/snackbar/snack_route.dart:289:18: Error: Too
    many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
    Try removing the extra positional arguments.
        super.install(insertionPoint);
                     ^
    Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
    build failed.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
```

These are the packages I have use in this app:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  json_annotation:
  audioplayers: ^0.15.1
  wakelock:
  shared_preferences:
  vibration: ^1.4.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.1.5+1
  flutter_icons: ^1.0.0+1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  get: ^1.15.2

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  json_serializable:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I have also tried to create a new project and copy all the code from the previous project to new, but still, it does not work. Can anyone help me how to resolve these issues.

Comment: Can you post the output of `flutter --version`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with the [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package. You are a lot of versions behind. Newer versions do not pass a parameter when calling `super.install()`, which is where your error comes from.

Upgrading to a newer version of the package will probably fix your problem. Unless you have a reason not to go for the newest version, I suggest changing the `get: ^1.15.2` line in your `pubspec.yaml` to `get: ^3.2.2` like this :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  json_annotation:
  audioplayers: ^0.15.1
  wakelock:
  shared_preferences:
  vibration: ^1.4.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.1.5+1
  flutter_icons: ^1.0.0+1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  get: ^3.2.2

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  json_serializable:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

While you're at it you might as well have a look at all the other packages you're using as well. Upgrading them to newer version might get rid of some other warning messages as well.